# Odoo 12 report invoice details on every page. How to achieve?

Tags: report, reporting, odoo-12, qweb

I am using Odoo 12 and have a legal requirement regardless report invoice and sale report.
I have to show the document details (document type, number, date, etc.) on every report page (not just the first one).

So, core Odoo report invoice allows me to print this information only at the first page.
In Odoo report invoice we have (at first page):

```
Customer Name
Customer Address
...
Country
VAT
```

Below we have document details with number, date, etc.

What I need to do is to show the document details on the top of the page (starting from page 2), like:

```
Customer: Customer Name
Document Type: Invoice
Number: INV XXX/2020
Issue Date: 10-10-2020
```

I am able to add the desired values to variables in qweb but don't now how to check if **page > 1**.

Can anyone help me include this information at the top of every page other than the first one?
I have searched and could not find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pmatos,

Try to add this to your report template. In this, you have to add on the header part with your Content Data(including document type, number, date, etc).

```
<template id="external_layout_standard_customise" inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('header')]" position="inside">
        <t t-if="o and o._name == 'sale.order'">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <h2>
                    <t t-if="not (env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma)">
                        <span t-if="doc.state not in ['draft','sent']">Order # </span>
                        <span t-if="doc.state in ['draft','sent']">Quotation # </span>
                    </t>
                    <t t-if="env.context.get('proforma', False) or is_pro_forma">
                        <span>Pro-Forma Invoice # </span>
                    </t>
                    <span t-field="doc.name"/>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </t>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @Dipen Shah - I have tried as you refer, problem is that any content I add to the header is is overlapping the top invoice content on the second page and forward. Please refer to: https://pasteboard.co/IU0Zv7c.png

Comment: Can you just adjust the Header-Spacing for your report template.

Comment: Great. I think this is the solution. My question is (language is still a barrier for me). Do I need to increase the header bottom margin or reduce "page" top-margin??? Can you please help me with some css or style for this?

Comment: You just have to increase the header spacing(means your spaces between the header & your Page). For the report look you can also add-on your style for top/bottom margin but that's up to your reporting style. And for the language what  you face issue?

Comment: Thank you Dipen. Will keep you informed

Comment: Hello @Dipen, just an update for you. I finnally did it. Had to "fight" with margin_top and header_spacing but I win this time. I will never touch this template again :o)

Comment: Bravo.! pmatos, Thanks for the Update.